# Ошибка Please verify that the build tool is installed and available to the IDE.

Tags: c++builder, borland

Я установил C++BuilderX 1.0 на машине с Windows XP.
Проблема в том, что не могу скомпилировать простейшую программу
с классической фразой ”Hello World!”, смешно и обидно.
Я получаю следующее:

```
Error executing command: CreateProcess: bcc32 @C:\DOCUME~1\Yauhen\LOCALS~1\Temp\responsefile41920~ error=2.

Please verify that the build tool is installed and available to the IDE.
```

Что было сделано не так?
Мои действия были такие:
File;New;New Console;
ввёл имя проекта: Hell
определил для него директорию: C:/Documents and Settings/rules/cbproject/Hell 
выбрал платформу: Windows
выбрал toolset: Borland Win32 Compiler Tools (Active)
ввёл имя .cpp файла: Hello

В файле Hello.cpp ввёл эту програму:

```
#include  iostream.h;
int main()
{
 cout"Hello Word!\n";
 return 0;
}
```

Выбрал команду: "Make Project"

Мне кажется, что я или что-то ещё не установил, 
или не сконфигурировал.
Пожалуйста, помогите в моих начинаниях!

Comment: Добавь std, <iostream>

Comment: тоже самое проблема в системе потомучто ниодин из компиляторов ниодну из програм не компилирует!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, надо писать так

```
#include  <iostream> 
int main()
{
 std::cout << "Hello Word!\n";
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: И получается таже самая ошибка